# Documentation for Xcode Source Editor Extension

Tags: xcode8, xcode-extension

I'm looking for some documentation of the new Xcode Source Editor Extensions in Xcode 8.

As far as I can see there is only the "documentation" found in the header file for XcodeKit. Would be great to get something that's more detailed and more official.

Answer (score 2):

Very preliminary [XcodeKit reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xcodekit) documentation is now available.

Our [WWDC 2016 presentation introducing Xcode Source Editor Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/414/) remains the best walkthrough.

The very shortest version, however, is: Because App Extensions need to be embedded in an application, you need to first create a new macOS Cocoa Application, and then add a new Xcode Source Editor Extension to that application. Then the [XcodeKit reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xcodekit) should help some in implementing that.

Comment: Hi Chris, great presentation on WWDC! I could not find how the extension is installed (after archiving). I noticed that once I run the App, it will show in the System Preferences under Extension. After that, moving in/out of the trash will show/hide it in System Preferences. Where is the extension getting registered? Is there a file somewhere in the user library (application support or other) that is created when the extension App is launched?

Comment: Launch Services keeps track of this. There’s no API to cause an extension to be registered.

Comment: If the Console of the Debug Area has a message similar to "IDEExtensionManager: Xcode Extension does not incorporate XcodeKit:", then go to the target of the extension, tab 'General' > Frameworks and Libraries and add XcodeKit *with* 'embed and sign'. In the template, Apple did add the Cocoa framework, but forgot XcodeKit.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a documentation but a good reference also
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/414/

Answer (score 0):

Extensions, at the moment, are poorly documented. There are a lot of assumptions made (for example, did you know that you can execute the container app? Yup, it’s really nice for settings GUI - see this [How To Execute Container App - Second Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413889/xcode-8-extension-executing-nstask))

At the moment, there are a lot of things missing: for example, there isn’t a structure that shows the corresponding lines with the data object - though this is quickly created with the following code:

```
    var matches: [NSTextCheckingResult] = []
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\n", options: [])
        matches = regex.matches(in: completeBuffer,
                                options: [],
                                range: NSMakeRange(0, completeBuffer.count))
    }
    catch {

    }
```

This gives you the location of all the `\n`’s - you should be able to fill out the rest to give you starting and ending positions which should match up to the lines.

All in all, there is a lot to like about the extension, but there are quite a few things missing as well.

Answer (score -1):

Currently the only available documentation is in the headers; there's nothing "unofficial" about them. If you have specific questions, please ask.

Comment: Well, that documentation is very terse and spartan, feeling as though it is a quick stand-in for now in lieu of richer documentation in the future.  For example, even such basic topics as how the identifierKey-nameKey and classNameKey-identifierKey dictionaries are to be filled out in commandDefinitions array of dictionaries is completely unmentioned.  Not even an example to mimic.

Comment: The current official documentation reminds me of a joke a comedian (Stephen Wright?) once told back during the 1980s:  guy: What's your phone number? gal: It's in the phone book.  guy: Oh, then what is your name? gal:  It's in the phone book too.  (There's nothing “unofficial” about the phone book, but, just as in the joke, the official reference doesn't really support the use-case very well.)